# SAS Sum daily date into weeks

Tags: sql-server, date, sas, aggregate, cumulative-sum

I am trying to take daily data (not every day has data) and sum it by weeks starting on monday. Below is a very small sample for the Data I have. the code is irrelvant for the summing purposes needed here.

Data have:

| ID | PKG | Revdt | code | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 70 | 17AB | 02AUG2021:00:00:00 | 01 | 7 |
| 70 | 17AB | 04AUG2021:00:00:00 | 02 | -10 |
| 70 | 17AB | 05AUG2021:00:00:00 | 01 | 8 |
| 70 | 17AB | 10AUG2021:00:00:00 | 01 | 7 |
| 70 | 17AB | 1QAUG2021:00:00:00 | 01 | 7 |
| 73 | 12AC | 02AUG2021:00:00:00 | 09 | 0 |
| 73 | 17AC | 07AUG2021:00:00:00 | 01 | 7 |

Data want

| ID | PKG | Revdt | code | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 70 | 17AB | 02AUG2021:00:00:00 | 01 | 5 |
| 70 | 17AB | 09AUG2021:00:00:00 | 01 | 14 |
| 73 | 12AC | 02AUG2021:00:00:00 | 01 | 7 |

I have tried the below

```
Proc sql;
    connect to odbc (dsn='' id='' p='');
    create table work.WeeklySum as select distinct * from connection to odbc
         (select ID, Pkg, datepart(week, revdt), code, sum(qty)
             from datebase
             group by datepart(week, revdt) );
disconnect from odbc;
quit;
```

However when i run it, it says "error:proc sql requires any created table to have atleast 1 column"

Comment: Did it run?  Did you get an error message? What message?  Did you get the wrong result? How was it wrong?

Comment: Edited it to include the error message "error:proc sql requires any created table to have atleast 1 column". it is running though. just not returning anything

Comment: Your query does have 5 "columns", but two of them do not have names.  Are you sure your SQL-Server specific query is valid? Can you try it using some other way of connecting to the database?

Comment: So when I remove the datepart(week, revdt) and just use revdt, remove the sum() and remove the group by it pulls in all of the data. So the issue seems to be when adding in the datepart as I tried it with just the date part and no sun but it still returned that same error

Comment: I also just tried to use an intx but no luck. Would this be easier is i just pulled the data and then manipulated it into the correct format?

Comment: `intnx` is a SAS function, so it definitely wouldn't work there.

Comment: You need to group by the first 4 "columns" you are selecting. `group by ID, Pkg, datepart(week, revdt), code`

Comment: Tried this just to see but didn’t have any luck either. Decided to just pull the data in then do a date part on it and work with the data after that. Note the cleanest but it works

Answer (score 1):

I would just pull the data with the daily rows first into SAS. If it is too big, write a macro to run it in loops with small chunks.

Once you get the daily dataset into SAS, create a separate table with weekly datetimes  (here I am creating a table begins with Jan 1, 2021 and has a row for every week from there - change the inputs according to your need):

```
data weeks;
format week_date datetime19.;
    do i = 0 to 52; 
    week_date = intnx('dtday', "01jan2021:00:00:00"dt, 7*i,'s');
    output;
    end;
drop i;
run;
```

Once you have this weeks dataset, left join your daily dataset to it using:

```
week_date <= revdt < intnx('dtday', week_date, 7, 's')
```

and then sum your variable by week_date.

Answer (score 0):

```
select ID, Pkg, datepart(week, revdt), code, sum(qty)
             from datebase
             group by datepart(week, revdt)
```

This is not valid in SQL Server, so this will be your problem.  SAS lets you do this, but when you do pass-through SQL, you have to follow their rules.  In the case of SQL Server, every variable that is not part of a summary function (here, `sum(qty)` is the only summary function call) has to be part of the group by.

If you want to group by inside SQL Server, you'll have to modify your query to be a join from the (ID,Pkg) query to the (datepart,sum) query.  SAS does this for you, but SQL Server won't.

Comment: So would i run the Pass through query with just the basic select statement/where clause and then have a sub query to convert the information into weeks. Or would i be better off just pulling in the data via a query and then manipulate it using SAS?

Comment: Sort of up to you, the advantage of passthrough is you pass a lot less data over the network; if this is a small table, then I'd just pass all the data. If not, then do it in SQL Server.  If you have SQL folks you can ask at your company, they can probably help you craft the SQL query.

Comment: Yeah it’s a giant database. The main issue is that I’m trying to update a tool that runs on sas already so I’m having to do everything via SAS.

So assuming I use a pass through to bring all of the data in, are there any good sas functions to convert that date from 05aug2021:00:00:00 to 02aug2021:00:00:00 (the start of the week -Monday). I tried searching for them and a date part would give me the week number which doesn’t seem incredibly useful since the data on the main table is in that week format

Comment: Doing everything in SAS is fine, but the inner query is in SQL Server *syntax* - so it would have to be something that could work in SQL Server directly, even if your tool itself runs in SAS.  I often open up SQL Server Management Studio to troubleshoot queries like this - I suggest you do the same.  You can't use SAS in passthrough - that's the point!